# RNN Tensorflow error

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to apply RNN algorithm with Tensorflow on my data. I tried many tutorials to implement it and all the tutorials are using mnist data. A tutorial had worked with me, but when I try to implement it with my data I face this error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights: 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell'; and the cell was not constructed as BasicLSTMCell(..., reuse=True).  To share the weights of an RNNCell, simply reuse it in your second calculation, or create a new one with the argument reuse=True.
```

I saw a lot of solutions but they didn't work. Adding `reuse=True` doesn't solve this problem.
Could you please explain to me this error and how to use the function: `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`.

The function of RNN is as follow:

```
def RNN(X, weights, biases):
    # hidden layer for input to cell
    ########################################


    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])


    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']

    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    # cell
    ##########################################

    # basic LSTM Cell.
    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    else:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)
    # lstm cell is divided into two parts (c_state, h_state)
    init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)


    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)


    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        outputs = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2]))    
    else:
        outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']    

    return results
```

Edit:

I would like to add a question to the previous problem. I did made some changes as suggested to solve the previous problem and it is working But I don't under stand if it is right. this is my correction:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.variable_scope("conv1"): 
    cell= tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=0.0,    state_is_tuple=True,reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False,scope="conv1")
```

This part is working but I would like to ask if it is right. I use this code to calculate training and validation data. The result is that at some point of epoch, the training loss decrease and validation test increase
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqKVo.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the part of the code in which you add the `BasicLSTMCell`s in the graph?

Comment: We need more of your code to understand the problem. Please provide in the question a piece of code where you actually build your graph... (not all of it, but all the RNN calls)

Comment: Sorry I edited my question and added my function. My comment was a mistake

Comment: Perfect! I'll look into it

Comment: How do you declare the `tf.Variable`?

Comment: I declared them as dictionary in python and initialzed the as random normal. for example: 'in':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))

Comment: Try to use `tf.get_variable` instead, inside a `tf.variable_scope`

Comment: Also, can you please test your function above with: `cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, reuse=tf.variable_scope().reuse(), state_is_tuple=True)`

Comment: I put the cell function inside a scope called conv1 and added the reuse command to the BasicLSTMCell and gett this error: Variable conv1/conv1/basic_lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?. I will try also to change tf.Variable to tf.get_variable.

Comment: Yes you should give a try. I'm actually not confident with this problem, this is why I'm only suggesting some minor edits... I don't have a direct and clear answer for you...

Comment: Also do not write your code to change functionalities by Tensorflow version. It may raise several issues. Write code that is specific for one version, then migrate it (following this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration)

Comment: I changed the tf.Variable to tf.get_variable but still get this error: Variable W_in already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?. I am always going between this error and original error. Maybe something of how I train my data but I am doing the normal training with multiple epochs and in addition the monte carlo simulation.

Comment: I added:tf.reset_default_graph() to the top my program then it is woring now. I would like to ask what does scope and get_variable changed?.